# You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed undefined

Tags: jquery, handlebars

Помогите найти ошибку.
Использую Handlebars и jQuery.
При оркрытии странички все работает, но если перейти на другую view и вернуться получаю ошибку в браузере:

```
description
:
undefined
fileName
:
undefined
lineNumber
:
undefined
message
:
"You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed undefined"
name
:
"Error"
number
:
undefined
stack
:
"Error: You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed undefined
```

Мой код:

```
<tbody id="user-list">
    <script id="user-records" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#each user}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{username}}</td>
            <td>{{role}}</td>
            <td>{{firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{lastName}}</td>
            <td>{{email}}</td>
            <td>{{notes}}</td>
            <td>{{activeState}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">[Delete]</a>
                <a href="#">[Edit]</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </script>
    </tbody>

function listUsers() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/users",
        success: userSuccess,
        error:  handleAjaxError
    });

    function userSuccess (userData) {
        let template = Handlebars.compile($('#user-records').html()),
        compiledHtml = template({user: userData});
        $('#user-list').html(compiledHtml);
    }
}
```

После многочисленных тестов, выяснил что ошибки нет если страницу перезагрузить. Пoлучается вопрос как сделать перезагрузку при смене View Single Page App?

Comment: Тут немножко не хватает кода, непонятно что значит физически "перейти на другую view" и "смена view". Я могу конечно напрячь хрустальный шар и предположить что аякс запрос завершается и обработчик вызывается, когда у вас уже нету в дом такого элемента, но сказать точно по этому коду - не могу.

Comment: Также если у вас реально Single Page App, то все-таки рекомендую готовый каркас взять. Если уж в реакте неохота разбираться, то хотя бы по старинке Backbone + Marionette. Иначе Вы соберете вагончик граблей и не доберетесь до задач предметной области вовремя.

Comment: не понимаю вопроса